# Any way to play video or launch to the video with flutter for web?

Tags: flutter

I would like to play youtube video or launch to the youtube url but I can't find a way because if you use url_launcher or video_player, flutter web won't be able to run and it says you can't run with flutter SDK.
So is there any way I can let user see the video?

Comment: Use flutter webview package. And add embeded html

Comment: Thanks for the informative comment, how can I do that? Sorry I'm newbie so.

Comment: What do you mean by **flutter for web**? is it aweb app or mobile one?

Comment: It's a web app.

Answer (score 1):

check out this example here:
[HTML PLATFORM VIEW example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/tree/master/examples/html_platform_view)

```html
void main() {
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'hello-world-html',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..width = '640'
        ..height = '360'
        ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
        ..style.border = 'none');

  runApp(Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-world-html'),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working import for ui in the non-forked flutter for web?

Answer (score 1):

I've detailed [here](https://medium.com/@constanting/flutter-video-player-3a2f4f8562a3) a solution that uses the [Afterglow](https://www.afterglowplayer.com) video player.

The Afterglow video player supports playing **YouTube** videos (and even Vimeo videos), so it will serve your case.

Basically you need to alter the **index.html** template file and interact with the DOM using either **dart:html** or [**universal_html**](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) packages to get your desired video playing. You'll need to know the video id of the YouTube video you want to play.

1. index.html will look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web YouTube Video Player</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1.x"></script></head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <a id="triggerYouTubeVideoPlayer" class="afterglow" href="#videoPlayer"></a>
    <video id="youTubeVideoPlayer" width="960" height="540" data-skin="dark">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. You'll need a **playYouTubeVideo** method like the following:

```js
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;

void playYouTubeVideo(String withId) {
  if(kIsWeb) {
    final v = html.window.document.getElementById('youTubeVideoPlayer');
    if(v != null) {
      v.setAttribute("data-youtube-id", withId);
      final a = html.window.document.getElementById( 'triggerYouTubeVideoPlayer' );
      if(a != null) {
        a.dispatchEvent(html.MouseEvent('click'));
      }
    }
  } else {
    // we're not on the web platform
    // and should use the video_player package
  }
}
```

3. And you'll play the video like this:

```js
playYouTubeVideo('5jidaSuRVKw');
```

You can replace this with any HTML/JS video player of your choice, the approach would be the same.

Before the 10th of December 2019, this method was one of the only ways of playing videos in a Flutter web app. At [Flutter Interact 2019](https://developers.google.com/events/flutter-interact) the web support for a couple of packages, including the [video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) package. The option presented above still work and may serve you better in your use case.

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58917425/1318946 Just copied and pasted 3 mins. Btw a nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to open the link but I still don't know how to play video.
I guess I should wait it to become stable.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;
onPressed: () {
  html.window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'Dummy');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Post Merge To Main Flutter library

I struggled with this for a while but currently you should be using the `'dart:ui'` library instead of the `flutter_for_web_ui` version. This still gives an error which you should ignore and run anyway.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory( // platformViewRegistry will show as error
          'hello-world-html',
          (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
            ..width = '640'
            ..height = '360'
            ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
            ..style.border = 'none');

      runApp(Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 640,
          height: 360,
          child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-world-html'),
        ),
      ));
    }
```

Here is the referenced issue [ui.platformViewRegistry issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41563)