# How can I implement video playback in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart-html, flutter-web

I'm trying to play videos hosted on firebase on my flutter web app.
I can't figure out how this will be possible.

With flutter native, the `video-player` plugin is used but that only works for ios and android.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to integrate video in a flutter web app?

I have tried using the dart:html package to achieve this. The videoElement class in the package looks relevant. But I'm unable to render the element as a widget.

```
    prefix1.VideoElement element = prefix1.VideoElement();
        element.height = 200;
        element.width = 200;
    )
```

I want to add a video playback option to my flutter web page.

Answer (score 3):

I've detailed [here](https://medium.com/@constanting/flutter-video-player-3a2f4f8562a3) a solution that uses the Afterglow video player.

You can replace this with any HTML/JS video player of your choice, the approach would be the same.

Basically, you need to alter the **index.html** template file and interact with the DOM using either **dart:html** or **universal_html** packages to get your desired video file playing.

1. index.html will look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web Video Player</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1.x"></script></head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <a id="triggerVideoPlayer" class="afterglow" href="#videoPlayer"></a>
    <video id="videoPlayer" width="960" height="540" data-skin="dark">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. You'll need a **playVideo** method like the following:

```js
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:universal_html/html.dart' as html;
void playVideo(String atUrl) {
  if(kIsWeb) {
    final v = html.window.document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
    if(v != null) {
      v.setInnerHtml(
        '<source type="video/mp4" src="$atUrl">',
        validator: html.NodeValidatorBuilder()
        ..allowElement('source', attributes: ['src', 'type']));
      final a = html.window.document.getElementById( 'triggerVideoPlayer' );
      if(a != null) {
        a.dispatchEvent(html.MouseEvent('click'));
      }
    }
  } else {
    // we're not on the web platform
    // and should use the video_player package
  }
}
```

3. And you'll play the video like this:

```js
playVideo('http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4');
```

Before the 10th of December 2019, this method was one of the only ways of playing videos in a Flutter web app. At [Flutter Interact 2019](https://developers.google.com/events/flutter-interact) the web support for a couple of packages, including the [video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) package. The option presented above still work and may serve you better in your use case.

Comment: The video play as an overlay on top of the entire Flutter app., How to play inside widget?

Comment: Use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

Answer (score 0):

The Flutter [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) plugin now supports web using the [video_player_web](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web) plugin through [federation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LD7QjmzJZLCopUrFAAE98wOUQpjmguyGTN2wd_89Srs/edit#).

Here is a quote from the [Pub page](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player_web):

> To use this plugin in your Flutter Web app, simply add it as a
>   dependency in your pubspec using a `git` dependency. This is only
>   temporary: in the future we hope to make this package an "endorsed"
>   implementation of `video_player`, so that it is automatically included
>   in your Flutter Web app when you depend on `package:video_player`.
>
> ```
> dependencies:
>   video_player: ^0.10.4
>   video_player_web:
>     git:
>       url: git://github.com/flutter/plugins.git
>       path: packages/video_player/video_player_web
> ```
>
> Once you have the `video_player_web` dependency in your pubspec, you
>   should be able to use `package:video_player` as normal.

Comment: but it still not support play video in safari on iphone

Answer (score 0):

the code below worked for me:

[Open
[image_picker_for_web / video_player_web] Can't preview PickedFile videos on the web
#58527](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/58527)

```
    void initializeVideo() {
    if (_pickedFile != null) {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(_pickedFile!.path);
      } else {
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(_pickedFile!.path));
      }
      _controller.initialize().then((value) => setState(() {}));
    } else {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(''));
    }
  }
```

based on code example above, i updated my code to:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      if (kIsWeb) {
        controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videoFile.path);
        ;
      } else {
        controller = VideoPlayerController.file(widget.videoFile);
      }
    });
    controller.initialize();
    controller.play();
    controller.setVolume(1);
    controller.setLooping(true);
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It throws EDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, MEDIA_ELEMENT_ERROR

Comment: i ended up hiring a developer from upwork. for me, the code was not producing errors, but the video created in flutter web version was not playable (maybe that's the not_supported error you are getting). upwork sent the video from flutter web app to an amazon server, used a traditional way to convert it to mp4, then stored in my firebase, and that worked. i have not touched the code in this part of the project for months and do not know why your coming up against an error.